# Changing the datetime format in php

Tags: php

Here is the format

```
'd-m-Y H:i:s'(15-11-2008  7:16:09)
```

I want to change to this format

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s' (2008-11-15 07:16:09)
```

Tried the strtotime() function, but it takes the 'm' as 'd' and 'd' as 'm'
Help! new to php..

Current code`

```
$dt = strtotime($this->input->post('insert_dts'));
$formated_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$dt);`
```

Comment: If you already know the format of the date, there's no need to use strtotime - instead use a function like [DateTime::createFromFormat/date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the existing date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code :

```
$dt = strtotime('15-11-2008 7:16:09');
echo $formated_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$dt);
```

Output :

**2008-11-15 07:16:09**

Comment: @SobinAugustine You can do like this `str_replace('/','-', yourdatevariable)`

Comment: *SobinAugustine: if this is not working for you, why did you accept the answer? *som: start using DateTime classes; your example will not work with dates after 2038 year.

Comment: @Glavic worked after doing this,
str_replace('/','-', yourdatevariable)

Answer (score 1):

Like @middaparka said in the comment, please use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '15-11-2008 7:16:09');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output is: 2008-11-15 07:16:09
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime('15-11-2008  7:16:09'));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these two methods in my base class(s) all the time...

```
protected static function Now() {
    return date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ;
}

protected static function NowStr() {
    return date_format(self::Now(), "Y-m-d H:i:s");    
}
```

Let me know if these work out for you :-)

Comment: function Now() could easily be `return new DateTime;`. And function NowStr() could easily be `return self::Now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: @Glavić: Yeah you're probably right, but how would that change/improve the functionality?

Comment: that was just my humble opinion, I like object oriented style more than procedural style. Examples are almost the same, but your function `Now()` will not work after year 2038 (19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT), because of the use of `date()` function. If you look at DateTime constructor (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) you will see that first parameter has default value "now", so if you need current time, just call function without parameters, like `return date_create();`

Comment: @Glavić: Ok understood. I was just wondering if I had a bug or it was slow or something like that :-)