# Is possible to change the format of a datetime-local input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

> NOTE: This question is not a **duplicate**, the reason is that I don't use only PHP, It's true that my pages are elaborated in PHP but with code of HTML.

I will repeat it once again, certainly I use php, but I use HTML in my PHP archives;  I'm working using **laravel framework** and also I use blade, I put the link from the page that was mentioned.

[Changing the datetime format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206530/changing-the-datetime-format-in-php)

**Now, I continue with explaining my problem.**

I have an input into a form and his type is datetime-local, the input show me the date in this format:

*dd-mm-yyyy 00:00*

But in my database the format of datetime is:

*yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00*

I already know that this datetime format is about my time zone configuration but If it's possible I would like to change the format, **visually and save as that format, just like in my database**. I'm talking only about the date, not the time.

I think that if is possible I will not have problems with my database.

If it possible, I would like to change the format using, javascript or in my function `save()` of my controller, create a way to change the format. My database is in mysql, I work in phpmyadmin.

Also I put my function `store()` of my Controller.

```
public function store(Request $request){


    $hours = new HoursNew();

    try {
    /*THE NAME FROM THE INPUTS IN MY FORM, 
    ALSO THE NAMES OF THE FIELDS OF MY TABLE OF MY DATABASE*/ 

        $hours->id = $request->id;
        $hours->time_start = $request->time_start;
        $hours->time_end = $request->time_end;
        $hours->estate_time_id = $request->estate_time_id;
        $hours->court_id = $request->court_id;
        $hours->save();


    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Ups! We have some problems to process your operation');

        return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');

    }

        Session::flash('message', "It's OK");
        return redirect()->route('ListHours.store');

}
```

NOTE: *Is not very important to my database but is important to know it*:

The seconds is not very important to save into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbon to do that.

Carbon::parse('your date')->toDateTimeString() should do the job.

Also, Carbon can create instances using the parse static method like this:

Carbon::createFromFormat('format','your data')->toDateTimeString()

Answer (score 0):

- Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to parse your datetime input into Unix timestamp.
- Use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert it into database format string.

  **Details**:
- `d`  Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   01 to 31
- `m`  Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
- `Y`  A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   Examples: 1999 or 2003
- `H`  24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
- `i`  Minutes with leading zeros  00 to 59
- `s`  Seconds, with leading zeros     00 through 59

Try:

```
// $input is your input datetime string
// $output you insert into Database
$output = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($input));
```